# What limits the core counts (up to 8) of ARM big.LITTLE/DynamIQ architecture?

Tags: arm

The previous ARM big.LITTLE supports four big cores and four little cores while you can only have 2 types of CPUs.

The latest DynamIQ can support more types of CPUs (e.g., a Tri-gear SoC from MediaTek presented in ISSCC 2022 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9731604). But it still only supports up to 8 cores. So in the MediaTek example above, you will see a 1+3+4 configuration.

The limitation is stated on ARM's website (https://www.arm.com/technologies/dynamiq). I wonder where the restriction comes from. What is more interesting is that I found Apple can break this restriction in M1 pro and M1 max while M1 still follows the 4 big and 4 LITTLE scheme.

Comment: I think the limitation is 8 cores per cluster, not 8 total cores. See e.g. 10 core big.little CPU implemented using multiple clusters: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mediatek/helio/mt6797t

Comment: The cores need to contend for memory. Cache can only do so much so you get a nexus point of throughput vs cores vs memory bandwidth.